# Highlight variable names in IDE by regex

Tags: python, regex, ide

I wonder whether anyone knows an IDE providing the feature to highlight specific variables given a regex expression. For example I would like to see a logger variable highlighted in my code so I can instantly differentiate the log calls from my application logic.

I am programming in Python (PyDev, PyCharm IDEs). Feel free to provide any IDE providing such support for whatever programming language.

**EDIT:**
An example:

```
logger.info("Opening the URL: %s", URL)
request = Request(url=URL, data=POST_DATA, headers=REQUEST_HEADERS)
http_logger.debug(request)
result = urlopen(request)
responseString = result.read()
add_reply_state(responseString)
logger.info("Received response: HTTP %d for URL %s", result.getcode(), result.geturl())
http_logger.info("Reply: Actual URL (%s), HTTP (%d), Metadata:\n%s %s", result.geturl(), result.getcode(), result.info(), responseString)
```

As you can see I have several loggers in my code. I'd like to highlight all variables that contain the "logger" substring in the name.

Comment: Could you give me a better example, with some code. I think PyCharm has this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm can, you can just use the find dialogue box, with regex enabled:

[image]

If you wanted something where logger, is making a function call:

[image]

I am not too sure about other IDEs, but I can do this in PyCharm.

Comment: This is a clever workaround. But I would like to have it permanently highlighted, not only during searches. Btw which coloring scheme is this?

Comment: @Eugen As in you want to automatically highlight variables that have a logger in them? That _is_ possible but very trickly and not to mention fragile.

Comment: @Eugen Its my own custom color scheme.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have that permanently highlighted (could be just the variable name or the entire line containing the logging call).

Comment: @Eugen There is another way, but I think its not much different from find. It will highlight the files important to you, but its rather inflexible. Because every time, you will need to change the specification.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) allows you to define your own language definitions, or modify the built in definitions. It's a little bit difficult to learn, but worth it if you really want to customize your highlighting.